# To whom should I write the email?

Tags: interviewing

Recently I had a phone call for a X position in a company.

They interviewed me and asked if I would also accept the position Y. I said "Yes".

Last week, I had a face-to-face interview in their premises, but for the position Y. The interview was average and I was not sure of the possible answer from their side.

Yesterday, I got an e-mail from the HR (not an automated mail, but a real person) and they told me that I was not accepted for the position X. However, I had the actual interview for the position Y. I am thinking of the following possibilities:

- They found someone else for position X and sent mails to the other candidates. However, I still have chance for position Y
- I am also rejected for Y, but instead, they just sent me this e-mail for position X since I know where else I have applied for.
- I am rejected for Y, but HR made a mistake with the position name.

Considering the worst case (the second and third), to whom should I write the email?

I have the emails of the person from the HR and also the manager who interviewed me. Is it acceptable if I directly contact to manager considering that he is busy and might not be able to answer the emails? I would like to do that to learn the actual status of my application.

Comment: You want to send the emails to do what? What do you want from the people that you are sending your emails to?

Comment: Updated the question. I would like to learn the actual status to clarify.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to contact the manager if he interviewed you, it's a part of his job. However, human resources do have to be involved in one way or another but it's not really necessary until you're all clear from the interviewer's perspective and if they're really interested in working with you then the interviewer should tell the human resources to contact you.

Comment: In my experience the first possibility seems most likely.  When they fill X they likely inform all applicants that made it to a certain point in the application process.

Answer (score 3):

I would contact the manager you interviewed with, briefly explain the situation, and ask if you are still under consideration for position Y.

In any event, you should be prepared for the possibility that you might not be accepted for position Y either, so you should continue your job search while you are waiting for a response from the company.

Answer (score 2):

Contact HR and straighten the mess with them. Reiterate to HR the positions that you applied for, and ask HR to confirm the status for each position that you applied for.

Feel free to simultaneously send an email the manager, especially since the manager is the one who sent feedback to HR, asking the manager to confirm your status for whatever position you applied for with him.

Comment: The problem is that probably the HR is not aware of the other position since I only applied for X (officially). Y was suggested by the manager.

Comment: @www if you interviewed for the spot even if it's not in writing you still technically applied. I personally would follow Vietnhi's advice. Even if this wasn't a formal deal HR should still be able to get you an answer. (I do like though asking the manager the status, making HR aware of the confusion... It's an elegant way of asking both parties without actually coming across as asking both parties)

Comment: I would start simple -- contact one person and get an answer, and the manager is more likely to know the answer or know how to get it. HR typically only knows what the hiring managers tell them.

Comment: @mcknz The OP states that the manager is a busy person. If the OP contacts both HR and the manager, chances are good that HR will get back to the OP before the manager does.